# Getting a value from a color picker and returning it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how you would go about getting a value from a color picker and returning it to a js script

Here is the HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css' />

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />



</head>
<body>
    <p> test test test</p>
    <div id="cp2" class="input-group colorpicker-component">
        <input type="text" value="#00AABB" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#cp2').colorpicker({
                color: '#AA3399',
                format: 'rgb'
        })
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
<script>document.getElementById("cp2").value = function () {

    return rgb;

    }
    </script>
`
```

I am looking to return the value of the color picker which is in RGB format  to a js script so that I will to able to assign vars like this

`var 1 = rgb[1]`
`var 2 = rgb[2]`
    `var 3 = rgb[3]`

`
    If you decide to help me I will be thankful and you could please explain so I can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Check javascript function:

```
<script>
           (function() {
            var rgb = document.getElementById("cp2").value ;
            return rgb;
            })();
</script>
```

Comment: so I removed my <script>document.getElementById("cp2").value = function () {

    return rgb;

    }
    </script>
and replaced it with yours and I can't get the rgb in the other js script

Comment: I replaced it but the rgb does not show up in intelisense in the other js code

Comment: try to alert and debug it